# Predict a cell value by month end

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say that we have Column Q (or 12) which has a header called "Days late". The values in this column increase by 1 automatically everyday. I would like to predict the value of this cell by month end, but the month end has to adjust automatically in order to avoid modifying the macro every month. I'm trying to predict which cells will be, let's say, 11+ days late, 31+ days late, 121+ days late and 300+ days late by then.

Comment: I do know EOMONTH, but not sure how to use it with today's date always varying.

Comment: Do you calculate days late by business (weekday) days?

Comment: No, every day of the week counts towards this number.

Comment: Try the formula below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go by business days:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0)) + Q# '(Q# being days late cell)
```

If you go by total days:

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(), 0)-TODAY() + Q# '(Q# being days late cell)
```

Once you create a column with this data, you can set up a "Conditional Formatting" for Days over 11+ days late, 31+ days late, 121+ days late and 300+ days late and highlight them differently.

Comment: You do have to change the cell type to "General" or "Number" (it formats as Date automatically)

Comment: Hi, this totally worked by adding it to my code! Thanks a lot!